# How to print Powershell Array Columns to Rows

Tags: arrays, sorting, powershell

I'm running a script to find any users in Exchange with folders within their Inbox. The return for one of the users is this:

```
$mailbox = @{Name=Test; FolderPath=/Inbox/Test; FolderSize=118.6 KB (121,475 bytes); FolderAndSubfolderSize=118.6 KB (121,475 bytes)} @{Name=Test Folder 2; FolderPath=/Inbox/Test Folder 2; FolderSize=0 B (0 bytes); FolderAndSubfolderSize=0 B (0 bytes)}
```

I want to take that data and send them an email listing the folders. I'm using this code for the body of the email: "The following folders are in your Inbox: $mailbox.FolderPath"

I want it to look like so (with the line breaks):

```
The following folders are in your Inbox: 

/Inbox/Test  
/Inbox/Test Folder 2
```

Currently it returns all on one line:

```
The following are in your Inbox:

/Inbox/Test /Inbox/Test Folder 2
```

How do I separate the entries on different lines? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$array = @("The following folders are in your Inbox: ")
Foreach ($folder in $mailbox.FolderPath) 
{
    $array += ($folder + "`n")
}
```

And $array will be what you put in the body of your email.

Comment: This did the trick. I had to replace the `n with <br/> because it is in the HTML email body but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That is how PowerShell displays generic arrays when cast as a string for output. A simple `-join` would suffice here

```
"1","2" -join "`r`n"
```

That will add a newline in between the elements. 
In your case you could have done something like this. Note: the variable `$mailbox` was a little malformed so I had to place in some quotes to make this work.

```
$mailbox.FolderPath -join "`r`n"
```

or like you say in your comments.

```
$mailbox.FolderPath -join "<br>"
```